# How can I map midi controller faders to midi CC values through software in Cubase?

Tags: midi, cubase

It seems like a simple question, but I'm at a loss. I have a simple MIDI keyboard with some knobs and faders, and I'd like to use one of the faders to control CC11. I cannot figure out how to do this, though. I can get expression no problem into the lanes in the key editor, but no option to link that to a MIDI control.

Currently I'm in the demo version of Cubase 7 (elements) so that *might* be why, but I don't know if I can buy this if I can't do this basic thing. I want to avoid setting the midi CC directly from my keyboard if possible, and most plugins have a simple midi learn function. So why not Cubase? Looking through the generic remote settings I can find a few parameters that are able to be automated but no simple midi cc stuff. Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You would normally use the Quick controls & midi device manager feature in Cubase to map your keyboard or use the ready made templates..But Quick controls is not available in the trial version of Cubase 7 Elements.

The only alternative is to use a midi plugin as a translator calibration tool... you would also need a chart of the midi specifications of your keyboard to guide you.

You would install the midi plugin as a insert on a track .The midi out from your keyboard is sent to the input of the plugin & transformed & filtered to suit your tasks..

Cubase has its own midi transformers but they may have also been disabled on the trial version.. You can find many midi conversion utilities & managers on the freeware VST sites.  It's good practice to own your own midi utilities so your not confined to a software brand. Which may  paralyse your workflow.

Answer (score 1):

After weeks searching, I have found what i think what you are looking for...
Select a midi track, go to Midi menu, List editor. There you can monitor midi activity and setup your preset for mapping events and actions.
In the evidence is the screen on the left.

Hope that helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wanna help, so don't judge me if I am answering this in a bad way (I can not comment). Just say that this is not what you're looking for and I edit this answer...

So, **first of all**, you need to figure of **WHAT IS A MIDI CONTROLER?**

---

### MIDI controller is used in two senses.

1. In one sense, a controller is hardware or software which generates
   and transmits MIDI data to MIDI-enabled devices.
2. In the other more technical sense, a MIDI controller is an
   abstraction of the hardware used to control a performance, but which
   is not directly related to note-on/note-off events. A slider
   assigned to open and close a low-pass filter on a synthesizer may be
   assigned to controller 18, for example. Changes in the position of
   the slider are transmitted along with "18" so that they are
   distinguished from changes in the value of other controllers.

*Part of my answer, you should say what is your Midi Controler to improve help.*

---

**Second**, my experience with midi controlers is only in Reason, in Music Producer, but the process is the same. **You got 2 ways**:

1. **WAY ONE**: if your Midi Controler is a specific know of the software (for example, if cubase has built-in all of configuration needed for your Midi controler) you can just set them ON. (see link below)
2. **WAY TWO**: if not, you need to configure all of your faders and knobs to do a specific performance. Check [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeNyL136b64) to know how.

Might this could helps...

Comment: Thanks for the attempt at helping, though I'm guessing this is probably not what they are looking for.  From the question, it sounds like they are familiar with how a MIDI controller works and are trying to figure out how to do your WAY ONE.  I could be wrong on that since I'm not the OP, but that's the impression I get from their question.  Granted I don't have a better answer since I've never used a Midi controller with Cubase.